# How to calculate average of a group when you know overall average, average of other group, and sample sizes per group?

Tags: mean

I know

- the average of a group that consists of two subgroups.
- the number in the two subgroups
- the total
- the average of one of the subgroups.

How can I work out the average of the other subgroup?

Basically, overall average of group of say 200 is 65%, subgroup B which is 150 has an average of 70%, subgroup C is 50. What is the average score of subgroup C?

Answer (score 1):

$m_1$ - known average in the first subgroup 
$m_2$ - unknown average in the second subgroup 
$m$ - known total average  
$n_1$ - number of points in the first subgroup 
$n_2$ - number of points in the second subgroup 
$n$ - number of points in total

You have 
$$n \cdot m = m_1 \cdot n_1 + m_2 \cdot n_2$$
So...
$$m_2 = \frac{n \cdot m - m_1 \cdot n_1}{n_2}$$